# A regex to remove whitespace and line breaks from HTML document

Tags: php, regex

I am using this regular expression to remove white space and line breaks from a HTML document.

However, it doesn't seem to handling line breaks very well.

```
preg_replace('/(?:(?<=\>)|(?<=\/\>))(\s+)(?=\<\/?)/', '', $HTML);
```

How can I improve the above?

I am only trying to remove spaces between beginning and end of HTML tags.

Comment: don't you want to use something like tidy?

Comment: I am already using tidy but it doesn't remove spaces and line breaks. I want to remove spaces such that my HTML document is on one line.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-strip-whitespace.php

Comment: What if the HTML document has multiple lines inside a `<pre>` tag? Removing those particular line breaks changes the way the document renders, and not for the better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this regex? It's not perfect (it only handles whitespace at the beginning and end of the line) but it works for me.

```
$html = preg_replace('/[\t\s\n]*(<.*>)[\t\s\n]*/', '$1', $html);
```

Comment: I think you're missing the second parameter of the preg_replace function. I tried the above and it managed to remove lots of HTML tags?

Comment: you need to remove the '$1', just an empty string declaration '' would work

Comment: It does not make sense to explicitly mention `\t` or `\n` when using `\s` because `\s` includes these characters. `[\t\s\n]` is more simply expressed as `\s` (no character class is needed).

Comment: Regex is also completely ignorant of what is and is not a "tag" in an HTML document.  In other words, using regex makes the process susceptible to damaging text nodes.  https://3v4l.org/gqGs0